# In designing a Javascript API, should I raise a TypeError or ignore with a console message?

Tags: javascript, api, typeerror

I'm having to make a Javascript API that is the public interface to a C-based API that has enumerations and required parameters. Javascript, being a loosely typed language, wouldn't offer the same kind of compiler warnings one might get when using a C-based API.

My question is when making a Javascript wrapper around the C API, is it expected in the Javascript culture that one would receive a TypeError when passing invalid data or would it be more expected for the API to output a message to the console and ignore the error?

Here's some sample code for the API...

```
var Foo = (function() {
  var foo = {

    Enum: {
      First: {value: 0},
      Second: {value: 1},
      Third: {value: 2}
    },

    bar: function(eenoom, aNumber) {
      if (!eenoom) {
        throw new TypeError("bar: You must specify the 'eenoom' parameter");
        return;
      }

      if (!aNumber || typeof aNumber != 'number') {
        throw new TypeError("bar: You must specify the 'aNumber' parameter (as a number)");
        return;
      }

      for (var key in foo.Enum) {
        if (foo.Enum.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (foo.Enum[key] === eenoom) {
            console.log("You did it!");
            return;
          }
        }
      }
      throw new TypeError("bar: You must use the Foo.Enum enumeration");
    }
  }

  // So no one can mess with our enums
  Object.freeze(foo.Enum);

  return foo;
})();

Foo.bar(Foo.Enum.First, 20);
Foo.bar({value: 0}, 20); // Throws a TypeError
```

Note the use of TypeError. Is this an expected way for a Javascript API to behave?

Comment: In general, if you detect a programming error (e.g. wrong code written), then you should throw an error to force the programmer to see and fix the error as soon as the code is run.  You want to make absolutely sure this error is seen immediately since the code can never work.  This would be different than an unexpected condition of some data that could just be a runtime condition (such as an empty array) where you might decide to handle that more gracefully.

Comment: This is opinion-based and therefore not a good question for SO

Comment: @Jamiec - There are plenty of possible answers to this that can be backed by well reasoned logic, not only opinion.

Comment: @jfriend00 - the fact that there a plenty of possible answers kinda proves my point.

Comment: @Jamiec - No it does not.  There are hundreds of thousands of questions here that receive many answers that are not all the same that are not based only on opinion.  A question doesn't have to have only one single possible answer in order to not be opinion based.  Geez.

Comment: For the sake of adding my *opinion*, look at how [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) behaves differently when in strict mode - throwing `TypeError` - perhaps you should consider something similar.

Comment: @jfriend00 Apples & Oranges my friend. There may be questions with multiple possible *solutions* but this one is based on an opinion on how errors should be handled. Replace "is it expected" with "what is best practice" (basically a synonym) and you have http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Answer (score 1):

I mainly do the following:

- In synchronous public APIs I always check parameters and throw the appropriate error. Not only `TypeError` but also other errors as appropriate.
- Generally I throw errors in exceptional cases - i.e. not fitting the thought-out execution flow.
- In asynchronous APIs I report errors via an error callback/reject function.

I think `console.log(...)` and go on is not a good idea. If the call did not met the pre-conditions of the API, the API contract is broken from the very start. (Unless the contract is, specifically "yes, I can handle bad input" which is quite decadent.)

In this case nothing that you do afterwards will be correct. So throw an error and break off.

As an API consumer I'd be grateful for a thrown error with a good stack trace and a meaningful error message - much more that for just a meaningfull error message in the console (which I may or may not notice).

Answer (score 0):

If the programmer has written code that will never work (not provided required parameters, sent the wrong type or order of parameters, etc...), then you want the code to fail immediately, fail visibly, clearly tell the programmer what is wrong and provide a stack trace that shows exactly where the offending code is.

The cleanest way to do that in Javascript is by throwing an appropriate type of error with a meaningful description.  The very first time this code is executed, it will fail and the developer will immediately know they have done something wrong.  This is what you want.  Anything else increases the chances that the developer does not immediately realize the programming mistake they've made or even if they realize something isn't working, it might take them significantly longer to figure out why it isn't working.

A `console.log()` statement has these drawbacks:

1. It may not be seen immediately or at all.
2. It doesn't provide a stack trace so it may not be obvious what specific part of the caller's code is causing the error.
3. Since the app may not fail noticeably, it may appear that nothing is wrong or nothing serious is wrong when in reality there is a major programming mistake that must be fixed.